# PHP: download/display focused images

Tags: php, image, loading

My page will have a lot of images, which will take a lot of time to load and will make it very slow, so my question is

how to make the page to download and display only the pictures that are being shown in front of you, exactly the same as performing image search with google, whenever you scroll it will keep downloading and displaying the focused images.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image lazy loading

eg Lazy Load Plugin for jQuery (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Demo: http://speckyboy.com/demo/lazy/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax, you can easily detect the view port by javascript and the images dimensions, so when scrolling, all you have is to send request to populate more rows of the view, this could be tables or div.

Comment: interesting to know, could you please send a link to similar sample project, if possible, i now its gonna takes me ages to figure how to that out,

Answer (score 0):

You can't do something like that in PHP.
It has be done in JQuery.

There is a plugin that does what you need, called Lazy Load.
Take a look on this site: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload